# How to test for the http ref in a link with Capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

```
<div id="look_here">
  <a href="stackoverflow.com"><img src="xxxxxxxxxx.xxx"></a>
</div>
```

How would you test for this link in Capybara (and RSpec)?

The image is dynamically generated, so I just want to test by `href`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
page.should have_selector "a[href='stackoverflow.com']"
```

See Section 5.8.1 Matching attributes and attribute values on http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
page.should have_xpath("//a[@href='stackoverflow.com']")
```